# Synchronizing between PC app and Android app

Tags: c#, java, android, windows

I have encountered a difficulty while trying to figure out how certain aspect of my program will work:
(There is no code written at the moment, only concept).

I have a PC application which I want to build with C#.
In addition I have few android devices with my java application on it, which will be dependent on the PC application but will have its own functionality.

The android application will have to read data from the PC application and vice versa as well.

At first I thought creating a server which all applications will read from.
But now I'm thinking maybe there is a easier, less complex way (since I have no idea about accessing to servers and I'll have to learn the entire thing) - creating a network and shared folders - now the PC application will save his data at the shared folders and the android application will read the data from the shared folder, every 5 minutes or something like that or create a listener that will update the application upon any change made by the PC application.
The android application will have to do the same, save his data at the shared folders and let the PC read from the shared folder.

Basically, this is my idea, now my question are:

1. What do you think about the implementation of the idea?
2. Is it possible to access shared network folder with android device?
3. Is it possible to add android device to home network?
4. The combination of C# PC application and java will be alright?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Answer of your questions :

1. This idea in implementable surely
2. I do not know for sure , but it should be .
3. Yup , it's very much possible using a WiFi connection.
4. This will not a problem as you have to use Webservice/Socket Programming (i will prefer for socket) where multiple platform is not a problem at all :)

Happy coding :)

Comment: Why i got a -1 . Please point out to reason so that i can improve my answer later :)